# Adding a LocalSearch facility to Leaflet JS Library

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to add a local search facility to the Leaflet JS Library, I have never used it before so not quite sure how to go about it. I have replicated how the zoom control works so I have added this extra function:

```
L.Control.LocalSearch = L.Class.extend({
onAdd: function (a) {
    this._map = a,
    this._container = L.DomUtil.create("div", "leaflet-control-zoom"),
    this._localSearch = this._createSearch(leafletmapsmarker_L10n.search_form, "leaflet-control-zoom-in", this._map.zoomIn, this._map),
    this._container.appendChild(this._localSearch)
},
getContainer: function () {
    return this._container
},
getPosition: function () {
    return L.Control.Position.BOTTOM_LEFT
},
_createSearch: function (a, b, c, d) {
    var e = document.createElement("a");
    return e.href = "#", 
    e.title = a,
    e.className = b,
    L.Browser.touch || L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(e),
    L.DomEvent.addListener(e, "click", L.DomEvent.preventDefault),
    L.DomEvent.addListener(e, "click", c, d),
    e
}
```

And then initiated this like so:

```
    _initControls: function () {
    this.options.searchControl && this.addControl(new L.Control.LocalSearch), this.options.zoomControl && this.addControl(new L.Control.Zoom), this.options.attributionControl && (this.attributionControl = new L.Control.Attribution, this.addControl(this.attributionControl))
},
```

So basically I need to figure out how to add the functionality for the search. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way but I can't find much information about this on the net, so could anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

try this new leaflet plugin:
[leaflet-search](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search)

and here can try more demos:

[https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/](http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/)